SSRS Report services, title - based on the selection from the parameters
I am tryin got do a title based on what the user select from the parameter -
Example - if user selected-
Purchasing -  then title filed should say Purchasing and MFG schedule
Purchasing Review then - Purchasing review and BOL
I tried the IF statement it didn't work

Edit your question and show how the parameter is setup. This should be simple but easier to answer with more info from you. Also list some of the other variants (different departments) so the answer will make more sense.

Add a placeholder in the title

And set the value to an expression

then set the expression to something like:
= Parameters!Department.Value & " and MFG schedule "& Parameters!Department.Value &" Review"

Thank you so much Dave, However i get both values.. I wants to say if i Parameter value - Purchasing then add MFG scheduling to the back if Purchasing review then ...
